# Strapi V.4 - Login API returns 404 - api/auth/local/

Tags: api, strapi

I have got Strapi 4 installed on Linux VPS and is working. I can call all other apis but not the Login api. It returns 404. Could not understand why? Have checked these thigs:

- Permission : Are allowed to public user for the api.
- Path : Tried both '/api/auth/local' and '/auth/local' urls.
- Other APIs : Can call them successfully such as '/products'

Have any body faced the same issue and can help?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you checked the callback inside USERS-PERMISSION.
[image]

Comment: Yes, check it in first place.